# Send actions to parent component?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've a template like this:

```
{{#the-table}}
   {{#the-row selectedRow=selectedRow selectRow="selectRow"}}
     <td>something</td>
   {{/the-row}}
{{/the-table}}
```

When I click on `the-row`, an action (`selectRow`) is fired.
I would expect `the-table` to receive the action, but instead it's the parent view/component the receiver.

How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `the-table` your yield statement should yield the context of `the-table`: `{{yield this}}`.  And then you should target the table from `the-row` using the `target` attribute.

```
{{#the-table as |table|}}
   {{#the-row selectedRow=selectedRow selectRow="selectRow" target=table}}
     <td>something</td>
   {{/the-row}}
{{/the-table}}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pizilunaqi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks, it actually works, even if then I have other problems with the item I pass from one component to the other... But I guess that's a different problem. Thanks.