# How to call Ember component from other component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-components

I have these components and I want them can be call from other component.

**templates/components/post-edit.hbs**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <form id="{{if isEditing 'form-edit' 'form-add'}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-result-placeholder"></div><!--.form-result-placeholder-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    {{input id="name" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" value=name required="required"}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="file">File</label>
                    {{input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1048576"}}
                    {{input id="file" class="form-control" type="file" name="file" aria-describedby="file_help"}}
                    <small id="file_help">JPG only, less than 1 MB.</small>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" {{action 'addNew'}} class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <a href="./" class="btn btn-secondary">Go back</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**components/post-edit.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from 'php-api-ember-test/config/environment';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        addNew() {
            console.log('hit on submit button from add page');
            this.get('addNew');
        },
        editSave() {
            console.log('hit on submit button from edit page');
            this.get('editSave');
        }
    },
    addNew: Ember.computed(function() {
        console.log('adding new data');
        var formData = new FormData($('#form-add')[0]);
        this.get('ajax').request(config.APP.phpApiUrl+'/add', {
            method: 'POST',
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            var response = error.errors[0].detail;
            console.log(response);
            // I want to call other component and render from here and put it in form-result-placeholder class.
            //console.log(Ember.Component.FormAlert);// undefined
            //$('.form-result-placeholder').html('{{form-alert}}');// not working
        });
    }),
    editSave: Ember.computed(function() {
        console.log('saving edit data');
    }),
    ajax: Ember.inject.service(),
    isEditing: false,
});
```

**templates/components/form-alert.hbs**

```
FORM ALERT!!! (this alert message will be change by ajax response. it is not static.)
```

**components/form-alert.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const FormAlert = Ember.Component.extend({
});

export default FormAlert;
```

I want to call `form-alert` component from inside **post-edit.js** file after **ajax** request.
I want to call other component and render after ajax request and put it in `form-result-placeholder` class.
How to call Ember component from other component and render into target element?

My Ember version: 2.8.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send actions to parent component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389578/send-actions-to-parent-component)

Comment: @lependu It is not duplicate. My question is call component from inside component js file. That question is call parent component from template tag.

Comment: You don't need to "call" a component. Just set a displayChild property on parent component, and show the child depending on that value. And you can toggle the property with the action like in the referenced answer.

Comment: @lependu The ajax response may have different result text messages, those messages will be display dynamically in the form-alert component.
To toggle property from template like that question is not possible, if it is then how can I set the message from ajax response?

Comment: You can set the result of the call as a property, and pass to the child. Which is displaying only that text.

Comment: Happy to help :) Altought, I think it is worth to mention, that component as definition knows nothing about the outside world unless explicitly passed in. So it would be the more ember-way to move that ajax call into a service and pass the result to the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389578/send-actions-to-parent-component) question. You need to use block form, and set the action on the child component.

Comment: No, it is different from that question please read my comment above.